# How to reads a string of maximum x characters in Golang using Scanf family?

Tags: go

Is it possible to utilize fmt.Scanf or similar functions in Golang to read a user's input from standard input, restricting the input to a maximum of x characters (e.g., 5)?

Comment: That's literally io.Reader's raison d'etre. What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I found examples like this:  `var username [10]byte
_, err := fmt.Scanf("%10s", &username)` but didn't work

Comment: 1. "did not work" is not a suitable problem description. 2 Just use the Read method. Or do you insist on fmt.Scanf? 3. Are you sure you understand "character" well enough?

Comment: I'm not being insistent, just curious. It would be quite neat if there was a way to accomplish it through formatting.